# Cuál es el tiempo máximo que puede pasar para que se actualice mi reputación al ganar puntos en reputación?

Tags: discusión

Cuál es el tiempo máximo que puede pasar para que se actualice mi reputación en mi perfil?? Pregunto solo por curiosidad, por saber cuanto tengo que esperar, porque hace como 10 minutos edité una pregunta, y me llegó la notificación de que había ganado 2 puntos de reputación y aún no se me ha actualizado.

Se que puedo simplemente esperar mas tiempo hasta que se actualice y no hacer la pregunta, pero solo quiero saber si existe un tiempo máximo definido para esto. Para saber cuanto tengo que esperar antes de empezar a preocuparme ;-). Saludos y gracias a todos por sus esfuerzos en este sitio.

Comment: No sé de tiempos, pero es prácticamente instantáneo, y no es algo para preocuparse. [Acá](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/9130/adriana-hern%C3%A1ndez?tab=reputation) figura el `+2` 13 minutos antes de tu pregunta.

Comment: No me había fijado en ese tag. Ok, gracias @Mariano